# Adding CSP to .Net React application

Tags: reactjs, .net, .net-core, single-page-application, content-security-policy

I have a .net core web application that is using UseSpa to server a react applciation.

I have added a csp which includes the below:

```html
applicationBuilder.UseCsp(csp =>
        {
            // If nothing is mentioned for a resource class, allow from this domain #70
            csp.ByDefaultAllow
                .From("https://localhost:5001/")
                .FromSelf();

            // Allow JavaScript from:
            csp.AllowScripts
                // need to remove this line ( need to maybe set nonce with ASP? ) #70
                // .AllowUnsafeInline()
                // .AllowUnsafeEval()
                .FromSelf()
                .From("https://localhost:5001/")
                .AddNonce(); 

            // CSS allowed from:
            csp.AllowStyles
                // need to remove this line ( need to maybe set nonce with ASP? ) #70
                // .AllowUnsafeInline()
                .FromSelf()
                .From("https://localhost:5001/")
                .AddNonce();

            csp.AllowImages
                .FromSelf();
            
            // HTML5 audio and video elemented sources can be from:
            csp.AllowAudioAndVideo
                .FromNowhere();

            // Contained iframes can be sourced from:
            csp.AllowFrames
                .FromSelf();

            // Allow fonts to be downloaded from:
            csp.AllowFonts
                .FromSelf();

            // Allow other sites to put this in an iframe?
            csp.AllowFraming
                .FromSelf();

            csp.OnSendingHeader = context =>
            {
                context.ShouldNotSend = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api");
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

I have added a nonce but and i am using MUI in the react SPA, i don't know how i get the nonce from the headers and where i need to put this nonce so that i dont get csp related errors for inline styles etc, I think i need to add it in the meta data in the public index page like so:

```html
    <meta property="csp-nonce" content="" />
```

But i do not know how to set this correctly?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to pass the nonce to the front end? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @JohnMcCollum I didn't sorry, please do comment if you manage to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your key problem is creating a nonce that gets added to the csp in the response header, but is also available in your view / html file.  I will provide one solution that works in .net 6.

In your program.cs file, you need to create the nonce, store it in the Context.Items dictionary, and then add the csp to the response header.

```
var app = builder.Build();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    //Create Nonce and store it in the context dictionary
    var randomNumber = new byte[32];
    string nonce = "";

    using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
        nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
    }
    context.Items["nonce"] = nonce;

    //Add the csp to the response header
    context.Response.Headers.Add(
        "Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", 
        "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-" + nonce + "';"  //replace this string with your actual csp
    );

    await next();
});
```

Now in your view, you can access the nonce with the value added to the context dictionary.

```
<script nonce="@Context.Items["nonce"].ToString()">
    some script here
</script>
```

You could add the csp to a meta tag, but there are limitations to the csp when you do this: report-uri (though this is deprecated, so this shouldn't be a problem), frame-ancestors, sandbox, and report-only won't work (are a few examples), so adding the csp to the response header is the best option.

Comment: how it will work for different apis and dynamic apis

Answer (score 0):

Nonces are for server-side rendered applications, which you don't appear to be using, so you want to use a [script hash](https://content-security-policy.com/hash/) instead to add inline scripts to your CSP.

If you have `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` enabled, your console will show an error message like:

> [Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-usNf4BJKM5+2IzarHkwVATPg24pwuR1jFPBAqWXmj+c='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

You want to take that specified hash value (`'sha256-usNf4BJKM5+2IzarHkwVATPg24pwuR1jFPBAqWXmj+c='`) and add it to your CSP like follows:

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'sha256-usNf4BJKM5+2IzarHkwVATPg24pwuR1jFPBAqWXmj+c='; style-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'");
```